# Getting values in between 2 floats

Tags: javascript, html

How would I get the value between two floats. I have two drop downs. Each option has its own value (price). And I want to find the price of all of the options added together from the option from the first drop down to the second dropdown. For example I choose “Gold 1”, to “Gold 3”, i want to plus all of the values of each option in between those two options. So “Gold 1” with a value of for example “2€”, “Gold 2” which is in the middle of those two, with the value of “3€” and “Gold 3” with the value off “4€”. With JavaScript. The drop downs and where I want to plus the values are in two different files. I have managed to when they click an option, the value will get stored in localStorage.

File 1 HTML:

```
    <option value="currgold1">Gold I</option>
    <option value="currgold2">Gold II</option>
    <option value="currgold3">Gold III</option>

  </select>
  <select class="selectDesired" onchange="listenToDropdownChange2();addDesPriceToLocal()" id="desRank">
    <option value="gold1">Gold I</option>
    <option value="gold2">Gold II</option>
    <option value="gold3">Gold III</option>
  </select>
```

File 1 Javascript

```
<script>
    function addCurrPriceToLocal(){
      var currRank_ = document.getElementById("currRank").value;
      if(currRank_ == "currgold1"){
        localStorage.setItem("currRankPrice", "€7.50");
      }
      if(currRank_ == "currgold2"){
        localStorage.setItem("currRankPrice", "€7.50");
      }
      if(currRank_ == "currgold3"){
        localStorage.setItem("currRankPrice", "€7.90");
      }

}

function addDesPriceToLocal(){
  var desRank_ = document.getElementById("desRank").value;
  if(desRank_ == "gold1"){
    localStorage.setItem("desRankPrice", "€7.50");
  }
  if(desRank_ == "gold2"){
    localStorage.setItem("desRankPrice", "€7.50");
  }
  if(desRank_ == "gold3"){
    localStorage.setItem("desRankPrice", "€7.90");
  }

}
</script>
```

File 2 HTML:

```
<button class="continueToCheckoutFinished" onclick="goToCheckout()" name="checkoutBtnFinished">Checkout</button>
```

File 2 Javascript

```
<script>
  function goToCheckout(){
    var currentRankPriceValue = localStorage.getItem("currRankPrice");
    var desiredRankPriceValue = localStorage.getItem("desRankPrice");

    var currpriceWithoutSymbols = currentRankPriceValue.replace('€','');
    var despriceWithoutSymbols = desiredRankPriceValue.replace('€','');

    var currpriceWithoutSymbolsasint = parseFloat(currpriceWithoutSymbols);
    var despriceWithoutSymbolsasint = parseFloat(despriceWithoutSymbols);


    var bothPrices = [currpriceWithoutSymbolsasint, despriceWithoutSymbolsasint];

    var largestPrice = Math.max.apply(Math, bothPrices); // 306
    var smallestPrice = Math.min.apply(Math, bothPrices); // 306


    function range(start, end) {
      return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
    }

    var result = range(smallestPrice, largestPrice); // [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
    alert(result);
    var difference = eval([result].join('+'));


    var rightPrice = largestPrice + smallestPrice + difference;
    alert(largestPrice + "-" + smallestPrice + "+" + difference + "=" + rightPrice);

    window.open("https://www.paypal.me/WAVEBOOSTING/" + rightPrice + "eur", "_self");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In what line are you having the issue? what is the input, what is the output and what did you expect?

Comment: No idea what the issue is, since the code shown is basically just text manipulation. Have you thought about the programming good practice of storing money as cents ( integer ) instead of euros ( float ) and only adding the euro symbol at the end? There's not a single reason why you have to store `€7.50` and then parse the heck out of it when you can just store `750`, do some basic maths and then divide by 100 and add the euro symbol when you actually have to visualize the price. Just a tip to save yourself future headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example, maybe it'll help finding something that works for your version.
Keep in mind that end users can change their localStorage, so keep that in mind if this is part of a real app.

```js
// All prices are in cents.
var PRICES = [
 { price: 750,  label: 'gold1' },
 { price: 725,  label: 'gold2' },
 { price: 750,  label: 'gold3' },
 { price: 875,  label: 'gold4' },
 { price: 810,  label: 'gold5' },
 { price: 915,  label: 'gold6' },
 { price: 365,  label: 'gold7' },
 { price: 1005, label: 'gold8' },
];
// Add an option item to both dropdowns for each price entry we have in our model.
// The big advantage being that adding an entry to thr prices is all we need to do to add more options.
// So we avoid having to add more option nodes to our HTML and avopid ahving to write if statements to get their value.
var render = function() {
 var price_start = document.querySelector( '#price_start' );
 var price_end = document.querySelector( '#price_end' );
 var options = PRICES.map(( entry, index ) => '<option value="' + index + '">' + entry.label + '</option>' ).join('');
 price_start.innerHTML = options;
 price_end.innerHTML = options;
};
var calculateTotal = function() {
 var index_start = parseInt( document.querySelector( '#price_start' ).value, 10 );
 // Since we want to include the selected option, index + 1.
 var index_end = parseInt( document.querySelector( '#price_end' ).value, 10 ) + 1;
 var sum = PRICES.slice( index_start, index_end ).reduce(( sum, next ) => sum + next.price, 0 ) / 100;
 alert( 'total of € ' + sum );
};
render();
```

```html
<select id="price_start"></select>
<select id="price_end"></select>
<button onclick="calculateTotal()">Total</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! And for taking your time. It works perfect! Thanks! But two things. How could i remove the value of the price_start from the total? I only want the in between. Plus the last value. And the second thing. How could i save the total? Without localStorage()? So the user can not change it.